# javascript: add script that will be evaluated before body scripts?

Tags: javascript

I have a script foo.js that is included in `<head>`. Inside body I have an inline script. Inside it, I want to add to the document another script for bar.js that will be loaded and evaluated before the inline script.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="foo.js" type="text/javascript"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      bar()
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In foo.js I want to add a script pointing to bar.js

bar.js:

```
function bar() {
  alert('hi');
}
```

What should be the code of foo.js?

NOTE: I know I can use onload in this trivial example. But in my real case, bar.js contains a function that is called several times and I want to be able to inline these calls in the right sections of the page (for code locality)

Comment: I'm not really understanding your question. What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have got two options:

1. Use `document.write('<script src="bar.js"></script>')` in `foo.js`.
2. Dynamically create and insert a `<script>` element within the head (since scripts in the head have to be loaded before the rest is parsed, this works):

   ```
   !function(){
       var s = document.createElement('script'),
           currentScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
       s.src = "bar.js";
       currentScript.parentNode.insertBefore(s, currentScript);
   }()
   ```

Comment: I tried the second option, unfortunately, I see (in Chrome) that the inline script is evaluated before bar.js

Comment: Wouldn't the first option clear the document since it's executing in the head?

Comment: @GGG No. I was also surprised when I saw it at first, but Google Maps does also use it, so it should be well-supported. EDIT: In [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9353610/938089?jquery-getscript-returns-an-parse-error-exception), in [this Google Maps file](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true).

Comment: I'll just take you on your word and +1 this ;)

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use the onload attribute to call the function you want first.

```
<body onload"bar()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me get this straight... You're trying to include a script that will run ***before*** the script that includes it? That makes absolutely no sense.

The closest I can figure out is trying to run the included code immediately, before proceeding to further code in the current script block. That can be achieved by fetching the script to include via a synchronous (blocking) AJAX call and running it through `eval`. This is overall a bad idea and there should never be any need to do such a thing - just put the scr

Answer (score 0):

I'd use jQuery's ready function that will fire when all the dependancies have loaded...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    bar();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are doing currently, the script of the head will be evaluated at **first** and then the one from the body.

But when the script of head is loaded, the script inside the body will not have been loaded yet. SO the function will be unavailable to it.

So you best way I know is to use `window.onload` which triggers the code once every DOM elements like script are ready for manipulation.

```
window.onload = function() {
   bar();
}
```