# Why migrating code to class structure breaks code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, google-visualization

This [Google jQuery GeoChart plugin](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart) works great like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
     google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
     google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

      function drawRegionsMap() {
        // code to draw map
      };

</script>
```

But moving the code into classes, breaks everything.  Browser is blank and status remains "transferring data from www.google.com."

```
(function( someClass, undefined ) {
    someClass.init= function() {
       console.log(google); //google object defined but next line breaks:
       google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']}); 

       ...remainder of code
    };
}( window.Project.Pages.someClass = window.Project.Pages.someClass || {}));
```

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Your code looks basically right, but you're missing a `)` after the closing bracket of the anonymous function. `}( window.Project.Pages...` => `})( window.Project.Pages` ... possibly the issue?

Comment: @George, you sure? why the `)` there?

Comment: Disregard, I was thinking the close-parens corresponding to the start of your block needed to go there, but it can go at the end as well. Herp derp.

Comment: Can you show a fiddle / live example. Because it works on my side

Comment: @Jashwant, it looks quite a bit like http://jsbin.com/inurif/edit#source but it doesn't work. I've moved the script to the head, and verified the code.  I think the real thing is problematic due to loading issues, integration with jQuery, google.load and DOM (see RobW's threads).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the way how Google loads their scripts. A simplified version of the problem occurred in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9748331/938089?mysterious-object-doesnt-support-this-methoderror-in-ie8-on-google-load): The problem was caused by the fact that the load of a Google script was delayed.

I've previously written a patch which is supposed to fix the issue, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9890299/938089?chrome-extension-unable-to-load-external-javascript-from-google-using-content-sc). Just evaluate the patch before using `google.load`.

Comment: I think you're right on about the problem. It now says google.visualization is undefined. I've loaded your patch dynamically and no luck.

Comment: @Emile I have tested and fixed my patch. The problem was that my original code contained single-letter variable names. For the sake of readability, I renamed `a` to `a_listener` in the function before posting, but forgot to rename the function argument. I've tested the code again, and it seems to work: http://pastebin.com/D6nyCxB4.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you mean but this works...

```
(function( someClass ) {
    someClass.init= function() {
       google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']}); 
       google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){ alert('setOnLoadCallback'); });
    };
}( someClass = {}));
someClass.init();
```

http://jsbin.com/inurif/edit#source