# phonegap - dynamically adding javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

Developing phonegap application which loads google map. Using below two javascript for google map. One javascript is loaded from locally while other javascript loaded from server.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.head.appendChild(script);
script.onload = function () {
    var script1 = document.createElement('script');
    script1.src = 'js/jquery.ui.map.js';
    script1.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.head.appendChild(script1);
    script1.onload = function () {
        alert(google.maps.LatLng);
    }
};
```

Both javascripts should be loaded after html page is loaded. Tried below code and referred various blogs, but its not working.

If same scripts written in header tag of html page, then it working perfectly. but in my application i need it to be loaded dynamically.

Please help....

**Solved:**

    `var doc_write = document.write; // Remember original method;
    document.write = function(s) {$(s).appendTo('body')};
    $.getScript('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true').done(function() 
           {
            $.getScript('js/jquery.ui.map.js').done(function() 
            {
                document.write = doc_write; // Restore method
                setTimeout(function()
                {
                    alert(google.maps.LatLng);
                },1000);
            })
            .fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception)
            {
                alert(exception); // this gets shown
                document.write = doc_write; // Restore method
            });
            }).fail(function() 
            {
                alert('failed to load google maps');
            });`

**Problem:**
It takes some time to initialise.

Comment: As you have tagged jQuery, You can use [$.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Comment: similar kind of issue i am facing.i need to implement recaptcha in phonegap.but phonegap passes request in 'file://' causing error

Comment: @Satpal Also tried with $.getScript, but same problem

Comment: Solved with these answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9353610/248889. But still one problem is there, it takes some time to initialise so it require to put timeout to call any function.

Answer (score 0):

Call your javascript function after device get ready function. Because if you are using phone gap through Xcode, the device get ready function take some time to load and your script is called before it.

Answer (score -1):

Don't do it in this way

Load it in footer section of your application

Comment: How can it be achieved on tap of button event in footer section? Please provide more info

Comment: Load it before tap of button, later you can modify map